# Activity holding memory in ImageViews causing memory leaks

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

Yesterday I asked a question about my MainActivity holding on to memory when I switch to a 2nd Activity.  @CommonsWare pointed me in the right direction to determine what was still holding on to memory using a heap dump but I couldn't get it to work with my "main" device.  I pulled out an old device and was able to finally get a heap dump through DDMS (the android studio one still doesn't work).  I analyized the dump and see that I have a lot of ImageViews that are still holding on to their bitmaps (drawable resources).  I have a fragment on my MainActivity that just houses a lot of buttons (in the form of ImageViews).  When I remove() that activity, the bitmap references are still there so I'm having to go to the onDestroy() method of that fragment and call myImageView.setImageBitmap(null); on all of them to see any memory freed up when the next Activity is loaded.  This works fine on my old device for every time I leave the MainActivity, but on my "main" device, it only works the first time after a new build from AndroidStudio.  If I then close the app (even force kill it in my app manager) then return to the app, it's still holding on to something when I navigate to my 2nd Activity.  But as I mentioned at the beginning of this post, I can't get a heap dump from that device for whatever reason to determine why.  I have two questions here:

1) is there a better way to free up the memory beyond myImageView.setImageBitmap(null);  I spent most of the day yesterday reading about memory leaks, what causes them how to avoid them etc.  I read a lot about something (context) holding on to my MainActivity instance and that could be the culprit.  I scoured over all of my code trying to find a place where I might pass the context to a sub class and only have one instance of that on my DatabaseAdapter where I pass getBaseContext() but I'm setting my DBAdapter class to null in onStop() of my MainActivity.

2) any ideas why on my "main" device (Samsung Galaxy S7 Active) the memory is only freed up after the first time the app builds from Android Studio but on my old device (One Plus Two), it works every time?  I would really love to be able to see a heap dump off of the GS7A, but alas, it will just flat out not produce one.

A few things I've tried:  I've tried setContentView() on the onStop method of the MainActivity to just a single view and that does not free up memory.  I've tried finish()ing the MainActivity when I move to my 2nd activity and that does not free up memory...the only thing that does seem to free up the memory is to reset my ImageViews to null and sadly, it's not consistent across all of my testing devices.

any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating those bitmap? For if yes, you should be calling bitmap.recycle before setting them to null.

Comment: I am not.  They're all drawable resources included in my project.

Comment: So obviously you are holding o to the activity context in a static or singleton variable. The solution is not working with onDestroy, just allowing GC to do its work, by not holding on to activity.

Comment: Ya, as mentioned in my OP that's what I suspected, but I've searched high and low for a reference that is holding on to it, and I can not find one.  I have no static variables on MainActivity nor do I *think* I have any singleton classes referenced.  I would love to post the code here for review, but it's 2800 lines of code and that's probably asking too much to have that looked over.

Comment: By old device...do you mean Android 2-2.3.X?

Comment: no..."old" to me :)  It's a One Plus Two running MM.

Comment: @lionscribe I'm new to using an HPROF analyzer so having trouble finding out what might be holding on to the activity's context.  Can you provide some suggestions as to how to find that out?

Comment: Try causing a GC after setImageBitmap(null) using DDMS or via code (`System.gc()`). Then take another memdump and compare